# Error in cloning repository with Git from R

Tags: r, git, github

I am new to Git and version control, so apologies if this is an obvious mistake. I have not found anything online that helped me solve this issue.

I have just done the following steps:

- Installed Git
- Connected Git and R with a SSH key
- Checked and confirmed that this worked

Now I want to:

- Clone a repository from my Github

When I put the command

```
git clone https://github.com/MY-USERNAME/MY-REPO.git
```

This gives me the following error:

```
fatal: bad config line 1 in file //MY FILE/.git/config
Unlink of file 'Filename' failed. Should I try again (y/n)
```

I checked the folder, and some folders and files are created (such as the config file). So clearly, the connection is there.

I have no idea how to fix this. Could anyone point me to the right resources?

EDIT:
The config file that causes the error looks like this:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github.com:Vera-Anne/BiPhD-ABM.git
```

Comment: You can follow [this guide](https://rap4mads.eu/git.html#installing-git), chapter 4 is about setting git repo, clone it to your computer and open it in RStudio.

Comment: Can you describe exactly what steps you took when you "Connected GIT and R with a SSH key" and "Checked and confirmed that this worked". So you are just running the `git clone` command in the Terminal window in RStudio? That should just be calling `git` directly without any involvement from R. Are you using RStudio?

Comment: @Barbara Gendron, Thank you but I don't think the problem is in setting up git repo's and cloning them (I have done this before on other devices). R clearly is able to communicate with GIT & Github, but there is an error in this process. The guide does not help with troubleshooting

Comment: Can you share the content of line 1 in that config file: //MY FILE/.git/config

Comment: @MrFlick: I went into R>>Tools>>Global options>>GIT/svn and set up a SSH key pair. I copied the public key into Github (Settings >> SSH and GPG keys) where I set upt the SSH key. In the git bash shell I used the command 'ssh -T git@github.com' that told me that I was sucessfully connected. Indeed, I am using the Terminal window in R, so directly running in git.

Comment: @ethanknights I have added this to my question.

Comment: I assume you mean RStudio rather than R. Those technically are separate things. Rather than cloning in the terminal, try in RStudio File...New Project...Version Control...Git. You can put in your repo URL. It way just be a problem of setting up directories correctly.

Comment: Thank you. Indeed, I do mean Rstudio, apologies for not being specific. Cloning by making a new project via version control gives me the same error.